How to add logical operator on logical source file
I have this logical source file:
A          S VALIDFLAG                 CMP(EQ '1') 
A          S ITEMPFX                   CMP(EQ 'PF')

But it seems that it works as an OR when I use the logical file using SQL. Where can I place the AND?
I checked this link but it doesn't have a sample for the AND.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=80-comp-comparison-keyword-physical-logical-files
I tried this but it is having an error on the AND.
A          S VALIDFLAG                 CMP(EQ '1') AND
A          S ITEMPFX                   CMP(EQ 'PF')


Is this question about IBM Information Server?  If so, please tag it appropriately.

The simple answer is that an AND syntax, is not supported.  Assuming that I am reading the documentation correctly.  But I also I think you might be misinterpreting something when you say "But it seems that it works as an OR when I use the logical file using SQL".  To me, that doesn't make design sense.  You don't validate that one of the fields of a file is valid.  You validate all of the fields.  That suggests that there is an implicit AND.

I tagged it as ibm-midrange because I'm doing it in AS400. I have tested a record and the ITEMPFX has 'XX' and is still in the logical file. Its VALIDFLAG value is '1' so I assumed it is an implicit OR. I saw other logical files can cater AND/OR at the same time it's just that I'm not able to find the source for those so I can use as reference.

But the question is not >about< [ibm-midrange].  It is >about< [ibm-information-server].  Isn't it?

@StephenC No, it is not about [ibm-information-server]. It is about DDS defined logical files on an IBM i server, so [ibm-midrange] is the correct tag here. This question has nothing to do with [ibm-information-server]

Combining conditions with OR:
 A          S VALIDFLAG                 CMP(EQ '1') 
 A          S ITEMPFX                   CMP(EQ 'PF')

Combining conditions with AND:
 A          S VALIDFLAG                 CMP(EQ '1') 
 A            ITEMPFX                   CMP(EQ 'PF')


Do you have a link for the documentation of this? Because I'm just wondering if it can do something like this: SELECT VALIDFLAG EQ '1' AND OMIT ITEMPFX EQ 'XX'. Since I can replace the S with O. Though this is just a hypothetical question.

Nevermind, I checked and this is an invalid scenario.

I personally once encountered exactly the same problem. I found the answer in the documentation "System i Programming DDS for physical and logical files". In the section Defining a logical file using DDS, chapter Simple- and multiple-format logical files in DDS it says:

"When using the select/omit fields, specify either S or O in position 17. By specifying either S or O, the
select and omit comparison statements are joined by OR. The system treats the select and omit
comparison statements that are joined by OR independently from one another.

That is, if the select or
omit comparison condition is met, the record is either selected or omitted. If the condition is not met, the
system proceeds to the next comparison.
By specifying a blank in position 17, the select and omit comparison statements are joined by AND. The
combined comparisons must be met before the record is selected or omitted."

You can
specify both select and omit for the same record format. The following information applies:
v If you specify both select and omit for a record format, the order in which you specify them is
important.
The select/omit statements are processed in the order they are specified; if a record satisfies a
statement, the record is either selected or omitted as specified, and remaining select/omit statements
are not examined for that record

Unfortunately, I can't give a link to this document - I found it online a long time ago and downloaded it in pdf format. Try searching. There are actually 4 of them:
Programming DDS concepts;
Programming DDS for Display files;
Programming DDS for physical and logical files;
Programming DDS for Printer Files

Although no.. I uploaded them to the cloud - you can see them here: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ALjgr0GzOMGD-w (look at other documentation)

Here is a link to the official documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=files-selecting-omitting-records-logical

Thank you all for your help. I really appreciate it.
